# UWP Bitmap-Icon is changing between Dark and Light Mode when hovering over it

Tags: uwp, icons, uwp-xaml

Whenever hovering over the icon it changes from light mode into dark mode. It starts with being in Light-Mode as it should be, but whenever I go over with the mouse it changes into darkmode
[image]
This is the Code for my Icon

```
<Page
x:Class="ticketer.Views.ContentGridPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:animations="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:models1="using:ticketer.Core"
Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="ContentArea"> 
    <controls:AdaptiveGridView
        Padding="{StaticResource MediumLeftRightMargin}"
        animations:Connected.ListItemElementName="itemThumbnail"
        animations:Connected.ListItemKey="animationKeyContentGrid"
        DesiredWidth="180"
        SelectionMode = "None"
        IsItemClickEnabled = "True"
        ItemClick="OnItemClick"
        ItemHeight="160"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Source,Mode=OneWay}"
        StretchContentForSingleRow="False"
        >
        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models1:ticketData">
                <Grid 
                    x:Name="itemThumbnail"
                    Padding="{StaticResource XSmallLeftTopRightBottomMargin}"
                    Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}" Visibility="Visible">
                    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White">

                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                            <BitmapIcon Height="30px"
                                    UriSource="Assets/ticket2.png"></BitmapIcon>
                            <TextBlock
                            Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopMargin}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextStyle}"
                            Text="{x:Bind TITLE}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please share the BitmapIcon parent control, it looks you have set the icon's Foreground in the visual state.

Comment: I hope this is what you mean

Comment: I have tried your code and remove not contained style, it works well in my side. [Here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/IconTest/blob/master/IconTest/MainPage.xaml#L13)is sample code.

Comment: Do you mean the style I set in the beginning in Page? Because if I remove it, it still changes color

Comment: It's strange, could you mind share min sample for us, I will test it base on your demo.

Comment: Can I send it to you, I dont want to share it completly

Comment: You could make a blank app only write above code (could reproduce the problem) and share us with github link.

Comment: https://github.com/philippfischer6/UWP-Demo

Comment: I checked it, it works well, please check this [screenshot](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgbAoiVcYf8EgNjMa3g?e=uzpFlu)

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: I did  nothing, just run your code sample.

Comment: Ok - strange, when i run it it still changes when hovering over

Comment: My OS version is 20h2, what about yours ?

Comment: I also got 20h2

Comment: Please try uninstall the app and clean your project, rebuild it again.

Comment: Doesnt change it sadly

Comment: Could you  try to test in other machine ?

Comment: My friend tried it on his laptop with the same git link and he had the same problem

Comment: Please check `AdaptiveGridView`  source [code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Primitives/AdaptiveGridView/AdaptiveGridView.cs#L23), so if you have override the default  `GridViewItemForegroundPointerOver`, it will change the default behavior. I will post an answer below.

Comment: I'm having the same or related problem. It only happens when the app is in light mode. I have BitmapIcons of png images in ListViewItems, they're black (the default foreground). Hover mouse it turns white, remove mouse and it stays white. I can probably fix this with a style hack, but this is clearly a bug. If this was intended behavior it would do the inverse in dark mode, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue, just for MenuFlyoutItem control icon (buttons, etc. are not affected). To reproduce:

1. Set RequestedTheme of your UWP Page to "Dark"
2. Set Windows Theme to Light (in settings of OS)
3. Have MenuFlyoutItem with your own white bitmap icon
4. Hover over the menu flyout item and when cursor leaves, icon turns black

Below, not perfect, but still solution which resets the icon right after. First register for PointerExited event of affected icon, in my case:

```
menuFlyoutItem.PointerExited += menuFlyoutItem_PointerExited;
```

Then add following method (you will need to little bit alter it to match your case)

```
    private void menuFlyoutItem_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            var DefaultTheme = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
            var uiTheme = DefaultTheme.GetColorValue(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.Background).ToString();

            if (uiTheme == "#FFFFFFFF")
            {

                string url = "ms-appx:///Assets/youricon.png";
                BitmapIcon x = new BitmapIcon();
                x.UriSource = new Uri(url);

                menuFlyoutItem.Icon = x;
            }

    }
```

This will reset icon image to your default right after the issue occurs. This is not perfect as you will see that image blinks once due to the code, but at least it will stay in requested color.

According to my opinion, this is a bug in UWP/MenuFlyoutItem or its Icon as (one of) these controls simply do(es) not respect the application's theme if its different from the system one.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in accepted answer is incomplete. It partially works, but it won't work when MenuFlyoutSubItem is closed. It also results in icon flickering. This can be resolved by very simple step:

Add following into App.xaml:

```
RequestedTheme="Dark"
```

Example:

```
<Application
x:Class="MyApp.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
RequestedTheme="Dark"
>
```

It seems that most of the Theme settings are inherited from Pages, but the menus directly take the Theme setting from app.

Answer (score 0):

> UWP Bitmap-Icon is changing between Dark and Light Mode when hovering over it

Please check AdaptiveGridView [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Primitives/AdaptiveGridView/AdaptiveGridView.cs#L23), it was inherit from `GridView`, so the each item will be rendered as `GridViewItem`. If we have override the default `GridViewItemForegroundPointerOver` resource, it will change the default behavior when cursor point over. Please add the `GridViewItemForegroundPointerOver` in to your `Application.Resources` like the following.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridViewItemForegroundPointerOver" Color="Black" />
```

Comment: When I do so, it changes whenever I hover over it to black, but it still changes into dark mode. When the app starts the icons are black, like they should be. When I first hover over they are getting white (dark mode), and not changing back. You code makes the icons black when hovering but when the mouse is not on the elements they are still white

Comment: It contains three keys `GridViewItemForeground` `GridViewItemForegroundPointerOver` `GridViewItemForegroundSelected`, you could give them specific value like above to process different states.

Comment: For this behavior, please try to set the GridViewItemForeground   as black.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help, but I dont know what im doing wrong, because all of this doesnt change this :(

Comment: When I set it to black it still keeps getting white on the first hover

Comment: And whats weird, only the icon changes, not the text undernealth

Comment: Have you tried use other image file to replace current one?

Comment: Yes different icon images have the same behaviour

Comment: I'm afraid I can't solve this problem, and your code sample works well in my environment.

Comment: This happens only when light mode for apps is enabled in settings. When Dark mode is enabled, issue does not happen. Happens despite having set Page.RequestedTheme = Dark....